# How to add 05:30 to Time column?

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

In my data frame I want to add 5hrs and 30minutes to the Time column and then group the Time field into 2 hours(0-2,3-6.. like this till 21-23). Here is the data frame below:

```
Time      Date          Device
7:12:20   12/14/2016    Tablet
8:57:34   12/12/2016    Desktop
18:48:36  12/1/2016     Desktop
4:27:34   12/16/2016    Desktop
5:57:48   12/28/2016    Desktop
10:28:31  12/20/2016    Desktop
10:28:32  12/20/2016    Desktop
```

Comment: it's giving me answer in "12H 42M 20S" format, I need in "hh:mm:ss"

Comment: Something like this perhaps `library(data.table) ; as.ITime(df$Time) + as.ITime("5:30")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be one way to handle your case. Your data is called `mydf` here. First, you can create a date object using `paste()` and `as.POSIXct()`. Since you want to add 2 hours and 30 minutes, I added 60 (sec) * 150 (min) to the date object and created `foo`. Then, I extracted the hour-minute-second part from `foo` and created a new column called `Time2`. The last job is to create a group variable with `cut()`. I do not know how you want to label the groups, so I named them as group 1, group 2, and so on.

```
library(dplyr)

mydf %>%
mutate(foo = as.POSIXct(paste(Date, Time, sep = " "),
                format("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"), tz = "UTC") +
                (60 * 150),
       Time2 = format(foo, "%H:%M:%S"),
       group = cut(as.numeric(format(foo, "%H")), breaks = seq(0, 24, 3),
                   labels = paste("group", 1:8, sep = " "),
                   include.lowest = TRUE)) %>%
select(-foo)

#      Time       Date  Device    Time2    group
#1  7:12:20 12/14/2016  Tablet 09:42:20  group 3
#2  8:57:34 12/12/2016 Desktop 11:27:34  group 4
#3 18:48:36  12/1/2016 Desktop 21:18:36  group 7
#4  4:27:34 12/16/2016 Desktop 06:57:34  group 2
#5  5:57:48 12/28/2016 Desktop 08:27:48  group 3
#6 10:28:31 12/20/2016 Desktop 12:58:31  group 4
#7 10:28:32 12/20/2016 Desktop 12:58:32  group 4
```

DATA

```
mydf <- structure(list(Time = c("7:12:20", "8:57:34", "18:48:36", "4:27:34", 
"5:57:48", "10:28:31", "10:28:32"), Date = c("12/14/2016", "12/12/2016", 
"12/1/2016", "12/16/2016", "12/28/2016", "12/20/2016", "12/20/2016"
), Device = c("Tablet", "Desktop", "Desktop", "Desktop", "Desktop", 
"Desktop", "Desktop")), .Names = c("Time", "Date", "Device"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Comment: @Harshkhandelwal I added the sample data that I created. Your real data may be different from mine. Can you test if my code works with `mydf`?

Comment: @Harshkhandelwal Then, you want to look into your real data. You may want to use `str()`, `summary()`, `class()` or `mode()` in order to check your own data. If you have factors, you want to think what you can do. :)

Comment: I uploaded the data in csv format and then extracted it into a new object. On that object I am performing all the operations.

Comment: @Harshkhandelwal Then, look into your data and see how you can apply my code above to your real data. :)

Comment: used Chron package and converted into ITime and IDate, worked perfectly. Thanks a ton!!

Comment: Glad to hear that!

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
hms("20:00:00") + hm("5:30")
```

is going to produce an object holding:

```
## [1] "25H 30M 0S"
```

Not exactly useful (in this context).

Here's a way to add the time and create the breaks:

```
df <- read.table(text="Time      Date          Device
7:12:20   12/14/2016    Tablet
8:57:34   12/12/2016    Desktop
18:48:36  12/1/2016     Desktop
4:27:34   12/16/2016    Desktop
5:57:48   12/28/2016    Desktop
10:28:31  12/20/2016    Desktop
10:28:32  12/20/2016    Desktop", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

library(lubridate)
library(magrittr)

(mdy_hms(sprintf("%s %s", df$Date, df$Time)) + hm("5:30")) %>%
  hour() %>%
  cut(breaks=seq(0, 24, 2), include.lowest=TRUE)
## [1] (10,12] (12,14] [0,2]   (8,10]  (10,12] (14,16] (14,16]
## 12 Levels: [0,2] (2,4] (4,6] (6,8] (8,10] (10,12] (12,14] ... (22,24]
```

Comment: It's not working, I have been able to add hours and minutes but not able to group then into 2 -2 hours.

Comment: I modified the `breaks` and included the output to show it does indeed work.

Comment: @hrbrmstr I like the sprintf idea. This is handy.

Comment: I am able to form groups now but there is absolutely no count present in those groups.

Comment: You need to do some work, like perhaps learn R a bit better, or at all (you provided no code). This is a code-helping service, not a code-writing service.  @jazzurro's answer was kind enough to do your day job for you.

Comment: I know it's not a code writing service, I recently started with R and that's why seeking help. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of doing it.

**Case 1 : Converting 5 hrs and 30 minutes into the seconds and adding it to the time column.**

*I must prefer before adding the time i.e 5hrs and 30 minutes you must merge the time and date columns in case you have time nearby 2100 hrs result in the change of date *

once you have join the columns you proceed with the following:

```
dataframe$newtime <- as.POSIXct(dataframe$dateandtimetogether) + noofseconds
```

**Case 2 : By defining functions for hrs and mins**

*In this case to you must join the date and time column, later it can be separated easily*

```
hrs <- function(u) {
  x <- u * 3600
return(x)
}

mns <- function(m) {
  x <- m * 60
  return(x)
}


dataframe$newtime <- as.POSIXct(dataframe$dateandtimetogether)  + hrs(5) + mns(30)
```

Comment: It worked, thanks. Still I need to group Time into a group of 2-2 hours.